# Making plot in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, plot

I need to implement some plot like [that](http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/docs/html/_images/bar_plot.png) or [that](http://graphjam.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/funny-graphs-leaving-on-a-jet-plane.gif) in my app ,
it can be even something similar.

I made a search on Qt web site with no progress , and I saw Qwt package but nothing similar there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800460/how-do-you-plot-points-in-qt/7841265#7841265) with source code for plotting points in a QGraphicsView very easily (11 lines of code). It doesn't seem like it does it out of the box at first, but it is just because the Graphics View Framework is a lot more powerful than a standard painter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I strongly recommend [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/).

Qwt is a mature, well-documented library and, I think it's fair to say, the standard solution for implementing plots and other display and control widgets in Qt.

If you need 3D plots, try [QwtPlot3D](http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: How about [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/)? It seems to be better option now.

Comment: QCustomPlot allows either GPL or commercial. Qwt uses the LGPL license. This is something that you must consider based on the project you're working on.

Answer (score 34):

I love QCustomPlot which is a Qt C++ library. It focuses on making good looking, publication quality 2D plots, graphs and charts and also has high performance for real-time visualization applications. You can get it here: http://www.qcustomplot.com/

Answer (score 8):

I'm using `Qwt` for that. The trick is to use a step function (see last example by this [link](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/curvescreenshots.html)), and shift the data by 0.5, so that bars will be centered to ticks. Here is an example of what you can get with alpha blending and anti-aliasing enabled: [my histogram](http://yury.chebiryak.name/histogram.gif).
Hope, you will do even better ;-)

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Qwt you might also consider [qt-plotting-widget](http://www.workslikeclockwork.com/index.php/components/qt-plotting-widget/) which may be a simpler option.

Answer (score 3):

**Qt 5.6** now [includes](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/18/qt-charts-2-1-0-release/) **Qt Charts 2.1**, which supports bar charts (as well as 7 other kinds).

Comment: Is it available in open-source distribution? I cannot seem to be able to use the `charts` module.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - It is available, but not included with the open-source distribution of 5.6. ("Open source users can build the module from the sources.") For some help with building with open source, see this thread: https://forum.qt.io/topic/66946/how-to-build-qt-charts-2-1-on-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

Qt has no support for plotting out of the box.

The most basic solution is to use [QGraphicsView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/graphicsview.html). Simply render your plot using the various items.

Other than that, you can follow [this thread](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2004-03/thread00114-0.html). It contains a couple of pointer to plotting frameworks but I don't know how useful they are or whether they are still supported in Qt 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

`QCustomPlot` is really easy to get started and there is plenty of Cartesian plot types you can do. Having said that, performance-wise it is not as good as other people say if you intend to plot large time series all at once. It internally uses a `QMap` to store the data which means that for every data point you insert or remove when populating, there is going to be one allocation / release of memory to add the data point to the map. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417703/how-to-plot-large-time-series-with-qcustomplot-efficiently/27417704#27417704) for more information.

Another thing I don't like is that even for simple plots it uses internally a struct `QCPData` that stores 6 double values when you would normally need two (`x` and `y`). That is, it triples the amount of memory you need to display a time series.