# How do you plot points in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, plot, qt-creator

I am writing an application in C++ with QT where you have n points and compute the convex hull of this.  However, once this is computed I have no idea how to plot the points and draw the border of the hull.  Making menu buttons and such is simple enough, but I'm not sure I know the tools to do this.

How do you do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: Making plot in Qt (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491362/making-plot-in-qt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just create a custom class deriving from `QWidget` where you override the `void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)` method. In that you put the points into some sort of point list, either `std::vector<QPoint>` or `QList<QPoint>` and then paint it with a Polyline method. For instance:

```
void Foo::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
  QPainter painter(this);
  std::vector<QPoint> points;
  // Fill points with the points
  painter.drawPolyLine(points.data(), static_cast<int>(points.size()));
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but got compilation error: 'QPainter painter' has initializer but incomplete type'

Comment: Well, the @Ohad may be long gone but for other passers by the "incomplete type"
error generally indicates that you are using a Qt object for which you have not included the appropriate header (i.e. add `#include <QPainter>` to the top of the file). As an aside it would appear that there is a header somewhere that provides forward declarations of all the Qt classes (i.e. `class QPainter;` and the like) making the compiler recognize that there exists such a class, but not know anything more about it and resulting in the unfamiliar error message.

Answer (score 12):

## Graphics View, `addEllipse`

`QGraphicsView` does 2D plotting very well and gives you many options for how to display it.  It  isn't as tailored for plotting scientific data as much as `qwt`, but just for showing a bunch of points, or geometry or animations and lots of other things it works very well.  See Qt's [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) documentation and examples.

Here is how you plot a bunch of points in a `QGraphicsScene` and show it in a `QGraphicsView`.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPointF>
#include <QVector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QVector <QPointF> points;

    // Fill in points with n number of points
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
       points.append(QPointF(i*5, i*5));

    // Create a view, put a scene in it and add tiny circles
    // in the scene
    QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView();
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    view->setScene(scene);

    for(int i = 0; i< points.size(); i++)
        scene->addEllipse(points[i].x(), points[i].y(), 1, 1);

    // Show the view
    view->show();

    // or add the view to the layout inside another widget

    return a.exec();
}
```

Note: You will probably want to call `setSceneRect` on your view, otherwise the scene will just auto-center it.  Read the descriptions for `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView` in the Qt Documentation.  You can scale the view to show more or less of the scene and it can put scroll bars in.  I answered a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830054/how-to-draw-a-point-on-mouseclick-on-a-qgraphicsscene/7831708#7831708) where I show more about what you can do with a `QGraphicsView` that you may want to look at also.

Answer (score 3):

There is a charting library, [qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/), that provides Qt widgets for - erm - charting purposes.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed this, but I'm hoping to do it with only QT, for compatibility purposes with some peers.

Comment: You can compile qwt right into your project, and it's Qt based. I don't see how this would affect compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

## Qt Charts, QML or GraphicsView

This was going to be an update to my QGraphics View example, but it got kind of long, and it really is a completely different method to answer the question.

Qt Charts (LGPL available since 2016) is a great way to do this without needing a third party library.

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-linechart-example.html
- http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/18/qt-charts-2-1-0-release/
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-overview.html

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineseries.html#QLineSeries

```
QLineSeries* series = new QLineSeries();
series->append(0, 6);
series->append(2, 4);
...
chart->addSeries(series);
```

For the convex hull example specifically, you probably want the `QAreaSeries` chart.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-areachart-example.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qareaseries.html

```
QLineSeries *series0 = new QLineSeries();
QLineSeries *series1 = new QLineSeries();
*series0 << QPointF(1, 5) << QPointF(3, 7) << QPointF(7, 6) << QPointF(9, 7) << QPointF(12, 6)
         << QPointF(16, 7) << QPointF(18, 5);
*series1 << QPointF(1, 3) << QPointF(3, 4) << QPointF(7, 3) << QPointF(8, 2) << QPointF(12, 3)
         << QPointF(16, 4) << QPointF(18, 3);
QAreaSeries *series = new QAreaSeries(series0, series1);
```

Hope that helps.