# How to draw a point (on mouseclick) on a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, mouseclick-event

I have the following code to set up a `QGraphicsScene`.  I wish to click on the scene and draw a point at the location I've clicked.  How could I do this?  This is my current code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);

    view->setGeometry(QRect(20, 50, 400, 400));
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(50, 50, 350, 350);
    view->setScene(scene);
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

UPDATE:  There is a new class called `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` that makes this a little easier.
I just finished an example using it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26903599/999943

It differs with the answer below in that it subclasses `QGraphicsScene`, not `QGraphicsView`, and it uses `mouseEvent->scenePos()` so there isn't a need to manually map coordinates.

---

You are on the right track, but you still have a little more to go.

You need to subclass `QGraphicsView` to be able to do something with mouse presses or with mouse releases using `QMouseEvent`.

```
    #include <QGraphicsView>
    #include <QGraphicsScene>
    #include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
    #include <QMouseEvent>

    class MyQGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MyQGraphicsView(QWidget *parent = 0);

    signals:

    public slots:
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e);
        // void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * e);
        // void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent * e);
        // void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * e);
    private:
        QGraphicsScene * scene;
    };
```

`QGraphicsView` doesn't natively have dimension-less points.  You will probably want to use `QGraphicsEllipse` item or simply, `scene->addEllipseItem()` with a very small radius.

```
    #include "myqgraphicsview.h"
    #include <QPointF>

    MyQGraphicsView::MyQGraphicsView(QWidget *parent) :
        QGraphicsView(parent)
    {
        scene = new QGraphicsScene();
        this->setSceneRect(50, 50, 350, 350);
        this->setScene(scene);
    }

    void MyQGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
    {
        double rad = 1;
        QPointF pt = mapToScene(e->pos());
        scene->addEllipse(pt.x()-rad, pt.y()-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0, 
            QPen(), QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
    }
```

Note the usage of `mapToScene()` to make the `pos()` of the event map correctly to where the mouse is clicked on the scene.

You need to add an instance of your subclassed `QGraphicsView` to the centralWidget's layout of your ui if you are going to use a form.

```
    QGridLayout * gridLayout = new QGridLayout(ui->centralWidget);
    gridLayout->addWidget( new MyQGraphicsView() );
```

or if your ui has a layout already it will look like this:

```
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget( new MyGraphicsView() );
```

If you don't use a `QMainWindow` and a form, you can add it to a `QWidget` if you set a layout for it and then add your `QGraphicsView` to that layout in a similar manner.  If you don't want a margin around your `QGraphicsView`, just call show on it and don't put it inside a different layout.

```
    #include <QtGui/QApplication>
    #include "myqgraphicsview.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);

        MyQGraphicsView view;
        view.show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

And that's it.  Now you are dangerous with `QGraphicsView`'s and their interaction with the mouse.

Be sure to read and study about Qt's [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) and the related [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-graphicsview.html) to be effective when using `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene`.  They are very powerful tools for 2D graphics and can have a bit of a learning curve but they are worth it.

Comment: phyatt, thank you very much about "Note the usage of mapToScene() to make the pos() of the event map correctly to where the mouse is clicked on the scene."