# Qt QGraphicsScene origin point

Tags: c++, qt

Whenever I add a new item to a `QGraphicsScene`, the origin of the `QGraphicsScene` seem to change for the position of the item I have just added.

How to make the `QGraphicsScene` origin fixed?

Do I need to add the item first in the QGraphicsScene and then specify a position for the item?

Answer (score 4):

Well, by default the content of the scene will be centered in the `QGraphicsView`. The origin of the graphics scene does not change randomly.

You might want to use [setSceneRect()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop) to define the size of the scene, so that the `QGraphicsView` always centers the scene in the view in a fixed manner. (If you don't set it manually, the rect will be calculated based on the items in the scene, which changes if you add more.)

Answer (score 3):

I answered a related question about a year ago that may be helpful:

[How to draw a point (on mouseclick) on a QGraphicsScene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830054/how-to-draw-a-point-on-mouseclick-on-a-qgraphicsscene)

Ditto to what badcat.

There are a lot of controls for adjusting or manipulating your viewport(s) that you have pointing at your scene.  The scene sets what is on the stage.  The view is how you look at it.  Be sure to set the `sceneRect` or set it indirectly using `centerOn` or `fitInView` or `scale` or `translate` from the `QGraphicsView` class.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html

Comment: Here's another question that might state the problem more clearly : what happens when i call QGraphicsItem::setPos() on an QGraphicsItem that has no parent item and which is not contained in any scene?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos "The position of the item describes its origin (local coordinate (0, 0)) in parent coordinates."  So in other words it sets where it will end up when it is added to a scene.

Comment: If you want to offset how transformations are applied to your object later (like make the center of a rectangle where it spins instead of the top left corner, use [`QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#transformOriginPoint) .

Answer (score 1):

QGraphicsScene::setSceneRect ( const QRectF & rect ) will make it absolute.

see http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop