# QT: Drawing Primitves to Follow Cursor

Tags: c++, qt

I am a bit new to QT. I have a separate `Crosshair` class that simply renders a crosshair using the `QPainter` and `QPen`. I used the `paint()` function and it does display the crosshairs at some position in the window. How can make the crosshairs follow the current mouse position?

This is my approach but I can't get it to work. I was following the VoidRealms tutorial.

```
void Crosshair::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){

   // i want to update the x and y position when the mouse moves
   //x = mouse.x
   //y = mouse.y
   QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
   update();
 }
```

Comment: you can use scenePos () or screenPos() api from QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent, to get mouse's x and y cordinate

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the QCursor class and QWindow::setCursor(const QCursor&) function, or is there a specific reason why you're re-inventing this wheel?

Comment: The class name is a bit misleading. I'm drawing primitives at the cursor position.

Comment: I renamed the class for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
this->setPos(event->x(), event->y());
```

There are also other helper functions available if you are doing a mapping to your scene when you are outside of `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`.

I described it here:

[How to draw a point (on mouseclick) on a QGraphicsScene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830054/how-to-draw-a-point-on-mouseclick-on-a-qgraphicsscene/7831708#7831708)

Hope that helps.

Comment: is it possible to do this without mouse click? I want the crosshair to follow the cursor at all times