# How to plot large time series with QCustomPlot efficiently?

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, qcustomplot

I am currently plotting a digital signal in Qt with `QCustomPlot` but it seems that when the number of samples is greater than 10000000 the operation becomes very slow. I have a `time` vector and a `data` vector and I'm setting the data like this:

```
QCustomPlot *plot;
QCPGraph *graph;
graph->setData(time, data);
```

Any chance to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because QCustomPlot uses internally a `QCPDataMap` (which is a `typedef` of `QMap<double, QCPData>`) this means that it is using a map to store the actual data sorted by `x` coordinates (keys). Unfortunately the `QCPGraph::setData(const QVector<double> &x, const QVector<double> &y)` method doesn't take advantage of the fact that samples could be ordered and doesn't use the insertion hint, so this improved results significantly:

```
QCPDataMap *data = new QCPDataMap();
size_t len = x.size();
auto xp = std::begin(x);
auto yp = std::begin(y);
while (len--)
    data->insertMulti(data->constEnd(), *xp, QCPData(*xp++, *yp++)); 
graph->setData(data);
```

I don't think that `std::map`s or `QMap`s is the best structure to store samples on X,Y graphs because a new allocation and release is done for every entry in the map and we are talking about millions of them. QCustomPlot should implement a custom map class with a custom allocator to avoid these memory issues.