# opening a project in Qt which already has been created in Qt

Tags: qt

I have created a simple GUI in Qt as a part of an example. Now I am trying to load the project in Qt again. So I go to **File -> Open File or Project**. Then I navigate to the folder that associated ***.pro*** file is located and open it. Unfortunately, none of the .cpp and .ui files show up at this point. It just looks like a blank project with nothing in there. Even in this condition, I can compile and run the project without any issue. I have tried 2-3 more projects that I already have created in the past and I see the same thing. Am I missing something here? Should I add all other files individually every time (really do not think so)?
I have also tried to open .user file in Qt, but it only shows XML file and nothing else. 
Thanks for your help

Content of .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-01-08T13:07:39
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = new
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: Are you talking about using Creator? Can you post some screenshots, the contents of your `.pro` file, etc.?

Comment: @peppe: thanks for your prompt response. Yes I am using Qt Creator 3.3.0 enterprise evaluation version. As I mentioned in my question, nothing shows up when I open **.pro** file.

Comment: Try to delete `.user` file and reopen the project.

Comment: @Nejat: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it and it didn't work. It still does not show anything in Qt Creator.

Comment: Why don't you use the community free version? Never the mind you can ask for help from Digia when you are using the enterprise version. I am not sure if it is possible during the evaluation period.

Comment: when I encountered this problem the first time, I simply thought that I missed something or made some stupid mistake. Because this is just unbelievably simple to be a bug in a software like that. 
I am new in Qt and I thought the community free version does not have all the features for GUI development. What are the differences between free and enterprise versions?

Comment: See the differences between licenses at http://www.qt.io/download/

Comment: @seyyedalipourmousavi You should use the enterprise evaluation if you want to buy a license. Otherwise go on with the free version. The free version mostly is sufficient for your needs unless you want some special features like Charts, Qt purchasing, Qt Quick Compiler, Boot2Qt,... which you should pay for.

Comment: @Nejat: Thanks man, I appreciate your help. As the last questions: I need to plot figures and bar charts in my GUIs, is it possible  in the free version of Qt? Is it legal to sell your applications created by free version of Qt?

Comment: @seyyedalipourmousavi There are some libraries you can use for plotting like QCustomPlot as I said here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491362/making-plot-in-qt/21530448#21530448

Comment: You can use the free community version of Qt to have closed source application and sell it using the LGPL license. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308153/can-i-use-qt-for-commercial-use-and-without-any-restrictions/23308943#23308943

Comment: @Nejat: Awesome, thanks for sharing your expertise with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sidebar is probably not set to show any project items. In "Edit" mode, click the drop-down menu on the top-left and select "Projects".

See also: [User Interface | Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is fixed now.